# How to create a certificate for my iOS App

Tags: ios

I started the enrollment process and now I need to create a certificate with the keychain tool on my MAC Book at /Application/Utilities

https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devbfa00fef7

It says "*Choose Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority.*"

I started the tool but I can't find no Certificate Assistant. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start keychain access look at top and follow this image

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: I did not noticed that menu at the very top, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) Click on Certificate
2) Go To menu And Click on Key Chain Access
3) Then Find Certificate assistant
[image]

4) Then Click on Certificate Assistant And Click on Request Certificate
[image]